How to reset or reverse instance transform without Realize Instances node?
I'm trying to reset or reverse instance scale. I have 3 Instances attach on Main object. Main object takes A as Instance, A takes B, B takes C.
I set a group input named Scale Fac to scale instance (Ins_A) in Main Object. Another group input named Map Range Fac controls the 'To Max' of Map Range node. The Map Range node will be use for some purpose later so i have to keep it.
The Ins_A and Ins_B have the similar structure with Map Range Fac A and B.
Now in Main Object, when i input the Scale Fac socket, all the instances scale follow their rules. However, I want the last level (Ins_C) to maintain its defalut size regardless Scale Fac in Main Object, but meanwhile Instance A and B transform normally.
The instances are objects. I don't want put them in one geometry nodes, so i can't use Realize Instances node.
I try to find an automatic way to 'reverse' the calculation of higher levels, but i can not transfer Scale Fac and Map Range datas between objects by Store Named Attribute node. I stuck here.
Any assistance will be appreciated.







After taking Driver into consideration, I find that is one way to transfer data between objects. I try Map Range and some other methods, they behave weird. Still looking for the right calculation.

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
The proposed approach relies on extra objects carrying the scaling factors of objects A, B and C to avoid cyclic dependencies. Consequently, the Input parameters are moved from the original GeometryNodes modifiers to the GN modifiers attached to these new objects.
The results are as follows for the Scale Fac value set to 1.0 and 0.5:


The original graphs are modified as follows:



The scale is recovered from the new objects made of a single vertex, instead of from the Group Input node. It is stored as a named attribute in the Point domain.
The new objects graphs are as follows:



They are derived from the original graphs to process the Group Input node data. Only the one scaling object C is modified to divide the scaling factor controlled by the Map Range Fac B parameter, by the scaling factor controlled by the Scal Fac parameter. Consequently, object C scale is affected by the Map Range Fac A and Map Range Fac B parameters, but not by the Scal Fac parameter.
NB: There is no need of the "Scale B" object for this demonstration. But to keep the symmetry of the process, object B is handled the same way as objects A and C.
Resources: 

Such a clear and concise solution. It works perfectly and inspires me more. Much appreciated !
